# Is it possible to obtain a UAA session timeout information in an SAPUI5 application?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, cloudfoundry-uaa, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cloud-foundry

In my SAP UI5 application, I'm able to obtain information about the user that is currently logged in via `sap.ushell.Container.getServiceAsync("UserInfo")`.

Is there a similar service that I could use to get the information about the session, specifically when it will time out ? Looking at the COOKIES, the JSESSIONID in the browser does not seem to have an expiration value set, but the sessions do frequently expire.